# Product API - 3rd party shipping prices

Tags: amazon-product-api

Is this possible to get ?

The issue is  that 3rd party lowest price for an item is useless most of the time as the "lowest current 3rd party item sold" mostly contain a shipping cost that very often exceeds the cost Amazon merchant seller with prime (no shipping).

Ideally I'd like to get 3rd party price plus the shipping price as an output